# Looping through ArrayList or ArrayDapter of ListView or the ListView itself (Android)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm wondering which way is best practice to access items of a list view in Android Studio.
Do I access them from the array list, array adapter or the listview itself?

e.g

I want to loop through the items of a list view:

```
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
ArrayList <String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add("x");
arrayList.add("y");
ArrayAdapter <String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Method 1:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
        arrayList.get(i);
}
```

Method 2:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
        arrayAdapter.getItem(i);
}
```

Method 3:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
        listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
}
```

NOTE: THE CODE IS NOT WRITTEN FOR TESTING. I'M JUST ASKING WHICH WAY IS BEST PRACTICE (COMPLEXITY WISE) TO ACCESS THE LIST VIEW ITEMS SINCE I BELIEVE ALL 3 METHODS PRODUCE THE SAME RESULTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practise is to get the item through the listview(**Method 3**)

In Method 1 and Method 2, you have to hold the reference of the list or the adapter after assigning it to the ListView

In Method 3, the ListView calls the adapter internally and all the necessary checks has been made in the method before returning the object.

**ListView Source Code**

```
 /**
 * Gets the data associated with the specified position in the list.
 *
 * @param position Which data to get
 * @return The data associated with the specified position in the list
 */
public Object getItemAtPosition(int position) {
    T adapter = getAdapter();
    return (adapter == null || position < 0) ? null : adapter.getItem(position);
}
```